# Using preg_match on embedded video code to pull out its id URL

Tags: php, mysql

I will be using a form to input embedded video code into a form field so it can be stored into a MYSQL database.
The iframe scrolling, width, height, frame border, and src should not be stored in the database. How can I use the php preg_match function to remove iframe scrolling, width, height, frame border,and src out of embedded video code. I only want the URL id to video. How can I store only the link to the embedded video and not all its attributes?
This is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'tutorial'))
{
echo 'Database not selected';
}

$title = test_input($_POST['title']);
$embedded_video = test_input($_POST['embedded_video']);

//I want preg_match to remove, src, iframe scrolling, width, height, and frameborder out of embeded code

if (preg_match(%^(src)"/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$embedded_video)) {

      //puting the URL of video in database
      $sql = "INSERT INTO person(title,embedded_video) VALUES ('$title', '$embedded_video')";
    }    
  }


if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
 echo "Not inserted";
}
else {

 echo "INSERT";

}



function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <input type="text" name="title" >
  <br>
  Embedded video:<br>
  <input type="text" name="embedded_video">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Insert">
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `preg_match()` a third variable, an `array()`. This will store the match on the first index and any part matches in the other indices.

I think this will be your solution:

```
if (preg_match(%^(src)"/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $embedded_video, $matches)) {

    //puting the URL of video in database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO person(title,embedded_video) VALUES ('" . $title . "', '" . $matches[0] . "')";
}
```

(You used an `}` too much after this `if statement`!)

For further reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php